# how to cover this for loop in batch test class?

Tags: unit-test, batch

```
for( Opportunity opp : opportunities ){

            // when individaul account has a household account
            if( mapAccountIndvAccIdToHouseholdAccId.containsKey( opp.AccountId )){

                Id householdAccountId = mapAccountIndvAccIdToHouseholdAccId.get( opp.AccountId );
                if( householdAccountId != null ) {
                    Opportunity oppToUpdate = new Opportunity( Id = opp.Id, AccountId = householdAccountId );
                    mapOppToUpdate.put( oppToUpdate.Id, oppToUpdate );
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you add your test class code as well?

Comment: in my test class i did not cover this for loop,if you have any suggestion regarding this for loop to cover you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

The question "how to cover this for loop" is the wrong question to ask. As presumably this code is the result of implementing some requirements, the question to ask should be "how to confirm each of the requirements is met". That typically means you will need several test cases and so several setups of test data, each corresponding to a requirement.

If you take this approach the test coverage will happen as a side effect.

(You say your code doesn't enter the loop - see [Create Test Data for Apex Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_data) or better still work through this [Apex testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing) module.)